# What Projected or Geographic Coordinate System should I use to calculate km distances between various points on a large scale map?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, distance

I want to measure distances using the distance matrix tool on QGIS between the yellow dots and their closest blue dot. I want my output to be in KM and to be as accurate as possible. I don't want to use multiple different zones like WGS84 /UTM zone 9N etc. Rather just a single system which will give accurate / relativly accurate results. 
[image]

This page has helped me to some degree (https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000006113) but I cant find the PDF to help decide which system to use.

I have tried using the distance matrix tool using WGS84 Psuedo Mercator but get my distances in Decimal Degrees which I've been told is nonsensical.

Comment: Where is your study region, there is probably a local projection that should be used

Comment: You try to compare distances with different projections, interesting discussion here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/151505/46073

Comment: Please check if the following is true: If you have your points layers in EPSG:4326, your project in EPSG:4326, and WGS 84 ellipsoid in the General tab of the Project Properties, the Distance Matrix tool returns ellipsoidal distances.