# Python shortcut to find the distance between two coordinates points from different zones

Tags: python, coordinate-system

I am trying to find the distance between two points on different coordinate zones. I am referring to this [Measuring distances when crossing UTM zones?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/151505/measuring-distances-when-crossing-utm-zones/388146#388146) and don't understand anything from it.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Unfortunately, "I don't understand anything from it" isn't a particularly useful Question here. Explaining topics that take a chapter or two in a textbook is outside the scope of our Focused question/Best answer model. We're more of a problem-solving site than a tutorial one. As to the title of your question, there really isn't any *accurate* shortcut, which what the reference Answer stated.